# VPN clients disconnection issue when connecting to WS 2012 on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpn, windows-server-2012

I have set up an instance on AWS EC2 running Windows Server 2012 as a DC and VPN server(RRAS). My VPN clients / colleagues work in different cities in China. They rely on this VPN server to access Google services.

My VPN clients in Shandong province, China, are facing issue using this VPN. They get disconnected automatically within an hour and they need to reconnect it. This make them very frustrated. However, VPN clients in Shanghai or Beijing don't face this issue.

I am trying to figure out the problem but I am not sure. I have few questions:

1. Does the instance type cause this ? I am using t2.micro.
2. Is the connection disconnected because of slow local Internet speed ?

I have went through so many troubleshooting but no luck. Can anyone explain to me the possible reasons or fix that can be applied ? I appreciate it a lot.

Thanks,
CK

Answer (score 0):

If there is no problem from other provinces, except one, then it shouldn't be the problem on the server.

You need check with the clients in Shandong:

- if they have any network/internet access issue
- if their own computer has firewall software installed to reset the connection in background, disable the firewall and try again.
- ping to VPN or run some network detection software to check if the network is stable or not.
- check in VPN log, if any error messages you can find.